# Adicionando Rich Snippet em varias divs

Tags: html, html5, seo, rich-snippets, microdata

Estou fazendo uma página que apresenta dados de uma pessoa. No inicio dela existe o nome e um texto, no final existe o endereço, e-mail, etc.

Estou utilizando **Rich Snippet**, mas todos os exemplos que encontro sobre ele, mostram toda a estrutura em uma única `div` que contem todos os dados da pessoa, o que não é o meu caso.

Meu HTML é mais ou menos assim:

```
<html>

  <row> 
    ...
    nome da pessoal
  </row>

  <row>
    ...
  </row>

  <row>
    ...
  </row>

  <row>
    ...
  </row>

  <row>
    endereço, telefone, etc.
  </row>

</html>
```

Não vou colocar tecnicamente como seria, porque a pergunta tem a ver com a arquitetura do Rich Snippet e não sobre a parte técnica de como se aplica.

```
    <html>

      <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <row> 
          ...
          <div itemprop="name"> nome da pessoal </div>
        </row>
      </div>

      <row>
        ...
      </row>

      <row>
        ...
      </row>

      <row>
        ...
      </row>

      <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <row>
          <div itemprop="telephone"> telefone </div>
          <div itemprop="email"> email@email.com </div>
        </row>
      </div>

    </html>
```

Repare que dentro de um único HTML tenho duas `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">` e essa é a dúvida:

Serão interpretadas como duas pessoas diferentes ou eu teria que colocar tudo dentro de uma única `DIV`?

Caso seja uma unica `DIV`, eu poderia te-la englobando todo HTML entre a parte inicial e final da pessoa? (Uma vez que a pagina toda é contem informações de apenas uma pessoal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade o que você está tentando utilizar é a [Microdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML)).

[Rich Snippets](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/) é quando se faz uso da **Microdata** através de informações específicas na estrutura HTML para fazer com que [motores de buscas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_de_busca) "entendam" o conteúdo do seu site e melhore seu índice nos resultados.

Respondendo sua pergunta, até onde sei, não é possível fazer com suas `divs` sejam interpretadas como uma só pessoa, pois cada uma está em um contexto diferente. É necessário que todos os `itemprop` estejam dentro do mesmo contexto de um único `itemscope`. Pois da forma como está, existem duas pessoas. (Além de não cheirar muito bem...)

Mas e o restante do HTML que não tem nada a ver com as propriedades da pessoa?

Não tem problema! Apenas as `divs` que você indicou como `itemprop` do seu `itemscope` serão interpretadas como tal.

Recomendo que você leia [esse material](http://w3c.br/cursos/html5/conteudo/capitulo20.html) para se aprofundar mais no assunto sobre **Microdata**. Já sobre **Rich Snippets**, não se esqueça de clicar sobre o link inserido no início da resposta e ler atentamente para que tudo funcione direitinho.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
<html>

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <row> 
      ...
      <div itemprop="name"> nome da pessoa </div>
    </row>

    <row>
      ...
    </row>

    <row>
      ...
    </row>

    <row>
      ...
    </row>

    <row>
      <div itemprop="telephone"> telefone </div>
      <div itemprop="email"> email@email.com </div>
    </row>
  </div>

</html>
```